# Unicode character Issue - openhtmltopdf library

Tags: java, html-to-pdf, openhtmltopdf

I use [openhtmltopdf](https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf) library (version: 0.0.1-RC15). I have a problem with unicode characters. In PDF file I see "#" symbols instead of "ă" and "ș".
How I can fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Can it be a font issue?

Comment: Yes, maybe. I've found a similar problem there: https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf/issues/70 


But I don't use any font for this text.

Comment: Can you please try to explicitly define a Unicode font in the CSS, like suggested here: https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf/issues/20#issuecomment-210754469 ?

Comment: I have ocrb10 font in my html template.
@font-face {
            font-family: ocrb10;
            src: url('${host}/ocrb10.ttf')
        }
 I've tried to add 'unicode-range: U+?????;' to this font-face but it doesn't work

I can not find ocrb10 font in Unicode.

Comment: What was the solution in the end?

Comment: @ndtreviv the problem has not solved yet

Answer (score 3):

In case it helps, we're using `com.openhtmltopdf:openhtmltopdf-pdfbox:1.0.10` and have found a way that works:

```
        new PdfRendererBuilder()
                .useFastMode()
                .useFont(new File(main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("arial-unicode-ms.ttf").getFile()), "Arial Unicode MS")
                .withW3cDocument(new W3CDom().fromJsoup(Jsoup.parse(html)), null)
                .toStream(os)
                .run();
```

In the html we have a `<style>` element that declares some css for the page, in particular:

```
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS";
```

Unicode characters then display as they should.

Answer (score 0):

I am using openhtmltopdf library. I had character problem too. Turkish characters looks like (İÖĞ -> ###).
People already say its about font problem.

I add useFont method like this and download tff file in resource/fonts/

```
PdfRendererBuilder builder = new PdfRendererBuilder();
builder.useFont(new File(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("fonts/ARIAL.TTF").getFile()), "Arial");
```